# How to forbid a dual-SIM system from using mobile data on one SIM?

Tags: mobile-data, android-11, dual-sim

I set the SIM card for mobile data like this:

[image]

And it works most of the time. This SIM is Austrian and I spend most of my time in Austria.

However, when I venture into Slovakia — the country of the other SIM card — strange things begin to occur.

Once I place a normal GSM call, or send a GSM SMS using the Slovakian SIM card in Slovakia I get a notification from the provider that I transferred 50kb of data and that they automatically assigned me 500Mb until the end of day. That is their policy.

I spoke to the provider and the lady told me that this is simply not possible and the problem is in my phone.

## **Could this be a bug in the Android OS?**

I am using a Samsung Galaxy A20e with Android 11.

Since I chose SIM2 for the mobile data, I don't even have an option to explicitly de-activate the data:

[image]

The evil SIM seems to have provided data for all sorts of apps:

[image]

**EDIT**

Mystery most likely solved — there seems to be a setting that overrides the ones in SIM card manager:

[image]

Comment: Check if you have activate VoLTE. Typically such "data usage glitches" are cause because the mobile network provider does not correctly identify a mobile data connection as connection only used for VoLTE. Starting with 4G there is no longer a voice network. I am not sure if the wrong classification is a bug of the MSO, the phone or both.

Comment: @Robert  Thank you! So far it seems you are right.